# Calling Java .jar Program from Perl using System()

Tags: java, perl, system

The title pretty much says it all, I am trying to get a java program (.jar file) to run from a Perl program.  I read another post on Stackoverflow saying this syntax is correct:

```
system("java filename.jar");
```

However this is giving me the following error.  I'm not sure if the problem is that it shows the filename as "filename/jar" instead of "filename.jar"

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: filename/jar
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: filename.jar
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use the -jar option to launch a jar.

> java [ options ] -jar file.jar [ argument ... ]

---

**Resources :**

- [sun.com - java](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html)

Answer (score 6):

You need to call it as `java -jar filename.jar`.

If you leave out the `-jar`, then java thinks you're trying to run a class named `filename.jar`, which it tries to load from the `filename/jar` file. Since you don't have that file, java throws the error that you see.